# How to animate markers in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this code that by the way is borrowed...

```
Ice Cream Sandwich compatible
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {

    TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
            return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        }
    };
    Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");

    // ADD THIS TO STOP ANIMATION IF ALREADY ANIMATING TO AN OBSOLETE LOCATION
    if(animator != null && animator.isRunning()) {
        animator.cancel();
        animator = null;
    }
    animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
    animator.setDuration((long) ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animator.start();
}
```

> what happens is that I have a problem in this line of code..

```
animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
    animator.setDuration((long) ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animator.start();
```

I use api 17 but the library FrameMetrics.ANIMATION_DURATION
works from api 24 onwards ..
and I want to continue working with the api 17 is there any way to give the same value as the library to my animator.setDuration () ???

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're using `FrameMetrics.ANIMATION_DURATION` for the animation duration only. You can use the desired value like 1000 or 100 or you can use Constant `FrameMetrics.ANIMATION_DURATION`'s value which maps to 2. Using constant value will remove the API 24's requirement as the minimum API. 
Use

```
animator.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
```

OR

```
animator.setDuration(1000);
```

Comment: thanks for answering
I had doubts in that line of code ... what happens is that the code that lends me
Within MarkerAnimation.java. It's the class where I have the animation.
If the animation duration is set to X, and you are receiving location updates in a rate smaller then X, multiple animations will be triggered, and you might see the marker animation flickers a bit..
To avoid that the code person uses the library that mentions the question but only works since api 24 and I use api 17.
and I didn't know what other option to use to replace that line of code

Comment: So using the code in this answer creates problem for you?